# Insert value of input as string in label

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to display the value of the input `#nom` as a string in the `label` tag

```
<input type="text" id="nom">
<input type="button" id="ok" value="afficher" onclick="affiche();">
<label id="msg"></label>
```

I have tried the following script, but it does not work and returns no errors.

```
function affiche() {
    var nom = document.getElementById("nom").value;
    $("#msg").val(nom);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a jQuery and plain Javascript salad, but assuming you actually have a reference to jQuery your problem is that `label` elements don't have value so `val` method does nothing. Method `val` applies only to input controls.

Use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to set `label` content

```
$("#msg").html(nom);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#msg').text(nom);
```

or better:

```
$('#msg').text($('#nom').val());
```